# look for duplicates matching two columns

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with two columns:

- Name;
- Code.

I am looking for duplicate rows: so if I already have a row with the same pair of name and code you should mark it as duplicated.

I will use this file to load data into a db. There I will do the same validation again (and I have no issues on this side) but I would like to do it on excel because I have 1k rows to check and the second validation is checking for the code to be unique only.

What I am doing so far is:

- new column with concatenate(name,code);
- pivot table to count the new values;
- manually fix the rows where the pivot table counts more than 1 value.

Is there a smarter way to do it, I'm pretty sure of it but I can't see it by now.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if I understand you correctly then the below formula should do the trick. There are various ways to accomplish this - this is just one of the ways. It will look for duplicate rows based on column A and column B but you can add more column criteria if you like. Add this formula to an empty column or with a conditional format formula.

=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1)>1,"Duplicate","")